# xamarin binding byte array to grid labels

Tags: xamarin, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I want to binding a byte[] to difference label in grid view but it is weird when I change the value in a timer event,the onPropertyChanged() don't call,turns out the label didn't update with the byte[].Pls help me out where is the mistake in my code.I can binding a byte with the code I list,but seems not work with byte[].Thanks!

```
System.Timers.Timer testtimer;
    Grid gridView;
    byte[] _recvdata;
    byte testbyte;
    public byte[] RecvData
    {
        get
        {
            return _recvdata;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_recvdata != value)
            {
                _recvdata = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RecvData");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public DevicePage(IDevice currDevice)
    {
        device = currDevice;
        this.Title = "Status";
        testtimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        testtimer.Interval = 1000;
        testtimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        testtimer.Enabled = true;

        gridView = new Grid();
        RecvData = new byte[40];

        for (byte i = 0; i < 40;i++)
        {
            string st;
            var lb = new Label ();
            st = "RecvData[" + i + "]";
            lb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, st);
            lb.BindingContext = this;
            gridView.Children.Add(lb, 0, i);
        }

        this.Content = gridView;
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte i;
        testbyte += 1;

        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            RecvData[i] = testbyte;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found that if I do "RecvData= somebytearray"that will work.But how can I update depands on one of the elements in the array?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter of RecvData property is not called when you just change it using [indexer]. You have two options I see:

1) manually call OnPropertyChanged after you change the byte array using indexer:

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte i;
        testbyte += 1;

        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            RecvData[i] = testbyte;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("RecvData");
    }
```

2) create a wrapper for byte array which would call OnPropertyChanged automatically when you change an array using the indexer:

```
public class ByteArrayWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    byte[] _array;
    public byte[] Array
    {
        get
        {
            return _array;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_array != value)
            {
                _array = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Array");
            }
        }
    }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _array[index];
        }

        set
        {
            _array[index] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Array");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

then instead of operating on your byte array like this:

```
public byte[] RecvData
{
 // get/set
}
```

you should use an instance of above class:

```
public ByteArrayWrapper RecvData
{
 // get/set
}
```

Other code should be just fine. If the binding doesn't work, maybe you'd need to bind to RecvData.Array[i] instead of RecvData[i], please let me know if that works as I'm not able to test right now.

Comment: is there any way do it auto? maybe a different getter setter?

Comment: you can create a class which would wrap byte array and implement an indexer, in which it would call OnPropertyChanged

Comment: may you give me a example code? i am a new learner, thanks a lot!

Comment: @zyyphilip I posted a quick example :)

Comment: sorry i am late! after i tried your suggestion,it successfully make it binding RecvData.Array[i] and change value by RecvData[i],thanks a lot!